# svn:global-ignores Not working? Tortoise SVN 1.9.7 / Subversion 1.9.7

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have the following file _svnignore.txt which contains:

```
bin
packages
debug
release
.vs
```

I have run the following command on reporoot:

`svn propset svn:global-ignores -F _svnignore.txt .`

I have the following folder structure structure:

```
reporoot/MySolutionFolder
reporoot/packages
reporoot/lib
```

When I do a commit through Tortoise SVN I am still seeing files in the path
`reporoot/MySolutionFolder/bin` to be committed when I do not want them to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved - the solution was to Commit *just the MySolutionFolder* folder to source control first and then apply the propset to the route.

Answer (score 1):

1. All *-ignore properties are applied **only** to unversioned items in your WC. If you have `reporoot/MySolutionFolder/bin` already versioned, they will not disappear from repo
2. I can't debug your patterns (I haven't SVN now), but you can, at least, check and show here results of

`svn st --no-ignore reporoot/MySolutionFolder/bin`

PS - work with commited to repo propset will be just "more correct" style, while it will not change common patterns